# Port 80 Drops ~50% of HTTP Requests, But Other Ports Work Fine.

Tags: wireless-networking, network-adapter

I'm in a new work environment and I've encountered the most aggravating issue in my existence.  Just about every other page doesn't actually load.  It's driving me crazy!  Everyone in a while, it simply won't load any pages, however, all of my other applications still work (I can talk on Skype, play multiplayer games, etc.).  It's a wifi connection (no choice).

If it means anything to any of you, if I disable my wifi adapter and then re-enable it, everything will work fine for a few minutes.  Also, I have to enter my unique credentials upon connecting initially and there is a proxy logging our history and such.

Is there a solution for this problem?  Obviously I don't have access to the actual network to make any changes.  Is this problem identifiable?

Comment: I'd blame the proxy. Perhaps the dropped requests are blocked websites?

Comment: @DarthAndroid :: Not everything is blocked.  It will often drop a request and upon refreshing load the page.

Comment: My next guess is the proxy is overloaded; As far as you've told us, it's the only thing that is different for HTTP connections over other types of connections.

Comment: I agree that this is probably the proxy. I've personally implemented HTTP proxy software, and I've encountered similar situations due to bugs in my own code. I can see how a shoddy proxy software (poorly tested, old version, in-house, or something like that) would exhibit this type of problem. If you can play games on ports other than 80, is there a reason you can't just bypass the proxy by connecting to a TCP VPN on a remote server on a port other than 80, and tunnel your HTTP through that? Seems like an awfully weird network architecture to allow non-80 and have a forced HTTP proxy...